# How do I remove or replace one of Scala Play's default plugins?

Tags: scala, playframework

I've written a `DBPlugin` for Play 2.11 that I'd like to replace the one that's normally used.  I've added my plugin to `conf/play.plugins` with priority 200, ie:

```
200:MyPlugin
```

When I start my app, I can see `MyPlugin` starting up, but then Play's default `DBPlugin` (an instance of `BoneCPPlugin`) starts up as well.  How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable `dbplugin` by adding the following line to your `conf/application.conf` file:

```
dbplugin=disabled
```

You can see an example of how to develop a db plugin here:

https://github.com/edulify/play-hikaricp.edulify.com/blob/1.5.2/module-code/app/com/edulify/play/hikaricp/HikariCPPlugin.scala

As you can see at the code linked above, you will need to override the `enabled` method to have your own way to enable/disable your plugin, based on another configuration key.

Comment: This disables my own plugin as well as the default one.

Comment: Is your plugin depending on `DBPlugin` in any way? Or is your plugin using `dbplugin` variable?

Comment: Also, which version of play are you using?

Comment: I added the Play version I'm using to the question.  Yes, my plugin is derived from `DBPlugin`.

Comment: You must then `override` the `enabled` method, as you can see [here](https://github.com/edulify/play-hikaricp.edulify.com/blob/1.5.2/module-code/app/com/edulify/play/hikaricp/HikariCPPlugin.scala#L29).

Comment: Ah, that was the missing piece.  Thanks!